# How to format the data we get from the uniq -c function in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, sh

Suppose I have data as follows in a text file called temp_data.txt:

```
"John","001-01-0001","engineering"
"Smith","192-11-0292","human resources"
"Brian","192-11-0292","operations"
"Lucius","992-11-0292","human resources"
"Smith","192-11-0292","human resources"
```

Doing a uniq -c on top of this yields the following result:

```bash
$ sort temp_data.txt | uniq -c > temp_data_count.txt
$ cat temp_data_count.txt
```

```
1 "John","001-01-0001","engineering" 
2 "Smith","192-11-0292","human resources" 
1 "Brian","192-11-0292","operations" 
1 "Lucius","992-11-0292","human resources"
```

How would i translate the data in temp_data_count.txt to look like follows:

```
“1”,"John","001-01-0001","engineering" 
“2”,"Smith","192-11-0292","human resources" 
“1”,"Brian","192-11-0292","operations" 
“1”,"Lucius","992-11-0292","human resources"
```

I have tried awk - but the data seems to get truncated at the end.

**Copied from a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76770292/how-to-format-the-data-we-get-from-the-uniq-c-function-in-linux/76773101?noredirect=1#comment135343516_76770292):**

I have tried `awk '{print "\x22" $2 "\x22",$1}'` - but this just truncates the original data and the final file looks funny. Also, yes I am looking to get the quotes and comma in the first column data, and sorting of the data doesn't really matter here.

Comment: How have you _tried awk_?

Comment: And are you sure you need those left double quotation marks around the numbers?

Comment: Computers are precise, and precision is required when working with them.  In this question, I would expect the output of your `uniq -c` to be in the order Brian, John, Lucius, Smith, but you show a different order.  Are you asking how to retain the original order? or are you asking how to add double quotes around the first column?

Comment: I have tried awk '{print "\x22" $2 "\x22",$1} - but this just truncates the original data and the final file looks funny.
Also, yes I am looking to get the quotes and comma in the first column data and sorting of the data doesn't really matter here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requested information to the question instead of using comments for this purpose.

Comment: `awk '{x=$1; $1=""; printf "\"%s\",%s\n", x, $0}'`

Answer (score 1):

A pure `awk` solution:

```
awk '{ a[$0]++ } END { for (i in a) print "\"" a[i] "\"," i; }' temp_data.txt
```

prints

```
"2","Smith","192-11-0292","human resources"
"1","Lucius","992-11-0292","human resources"
"1","Brian","192-11-0292","operations"
"1","John","001-01-0001","engineering"
```

provided that I fixed the different trailing spaces in the data copied from the question. (The order is unspecified.)

This solution uses the whole input line as a key for an associative array and increments the value to count the number of identic lines. At the end, the array keys (= input lines) and values (= counters) are prointed in a loop in the specified format.

---

With GNU `awk` you can get sorted output by setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`.

For example

```
awk '{ a[$0]++ } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; for (i in a) print "\"" a[i] "\"," i; }' temp_data.txt
```

results in sorting by the values as strings in ascending order.

```
"1","Brian","192-11-0292","operations"
"1","John","001-01-0001","engineering"
"1","Lucius","992-11-0292","human resources"
"2","Smith","192-11-0292","human resources"
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html

---

Or another `sed` post-processing

```
sort temp_data.txt|uniq -c|sed 's/^\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*/"\1",/'
```

replaces at the beginning of the line any number of spaces followed by any number of digits (captured as group 1) followed by any number of spaces with the captured digits surrounded by quotes and comma.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\s*//g;s/^[0-9]*/"&",/g;s/, "/,"/g' temp_data_count.txt
```

Which will give you the result:

```
"1","Brian","192-11-0292","operations"
"1","John","001-01-0001","engineering"
"1","Lucius","992-11-0292","human resources"
"2","Smith","192-11-0292","human resources"
```

It uses three substitutions in order:

1. `s/^\s*//g` will remove the leading whitespace (from `uniq -c` output)
2. `s/^[0-9]*/"&",/g` will grab the first number and place it with quotes and a comma
3. `s/, "/,"/g` removes the space that was left after the number

Comment: Or a bit shorter with a single substitution: `sort temp_data.txt|uniq -c|sed 's/^\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*/"\1",/'`

Comment: Ah yes, that was I was going for, but failed at, I should have escaped the ( )'s.

Answer (score 0):

You were close: <strike>`sort temp_data.txt | uniq -c | awk -v OFS=, '{print "\"" $1 "\"", $2}'`</strike>

---

Sorry, that was completely wrong.

[@Bodo shows how to do it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76773082/7552), with unordered and sorted output.
To maintain the original order, we need to keep track of the line number when we first saw each record. Using GNU awk specifically

```bash
gawk '
  !lineno[$0] {lineno[$0] = NR}
  {count[$0]++}
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
    for (line in lineno)
      printf "\"%d\",%s\n", count[line], line
  }
' temp_data.txt
```

```
"1","John","001-01-0001","engineering"
"2","Smith","192-11-0292","human resources"
"1","Brian","192-11-0292","operations"
"1","Lucius","992-11-0292","human resources"
```

With any awk, this will produce the same output, looping over the file twice

```bash
awk '
  NR == FNR {count[$0]++; next}
  !seen[$0]++ {printf "\"%d\",%s\n", count[$0], $0}
' temp_data.txt temp_data.txt
```